# DRYing out redundant locking code using delegates

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, dry

I have a class that has about a dozen methods that look like this:

```
public Result Parse(string input)
{
   InitLock.EnterReadLock(); //Block while database is being initialized
   try
   {
      return parser.Parse(input);
   }
   finally
   {
      InitLock.ExitReadLock();
   }
}
```

The return type and the input parameter differs, but I always enter a read lock, perform some sort of action, and exit the read lock.  I'm wondering if it's possible to create a utility function to handle the locking for me.  So, I've come up with this:

```
static TResult DoWithLock<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> action, T p)
{
   InitLock.EnterReadLock(); //Block while database is being initialized
   try
   {
      return action(p);
   }
   finally
   {
      InitLock.ExitReadLock();
   }
}
```

Now I can simplify the method above down to:

```
public Result Parse(string input)
{
   return DoWithLock(x => parser.Parse(x), input);
}
```

This works, however two things kind of annoy me.  First, the utility method assumes there's a return value and one and only one parameter.  If I want to wrap a function that has more than one parameter, or no return value, I'd have to create overloads for these cases.  Two, I think it's a bit weird to pass `input` to the `Func<>` and then refer to it again using `x`.  Basically, `x` and `input` are the same thing.  Maybe I could refer to `input` using closures, however then I have no idea what I'd pass in to `action()`.

Is there a way to improve this utility method to work a bit better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my answer here (note that it is not the accepted answer, but it performs substantially better than the accepted answer):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1150287/138304

Your code simplifies to this:

```
public Result Parse(string input)
{
   using (InitLock.ReadLock())
   {
      return parser.Parse(input);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely an interesting approach!